# Create a PHP file using PHP?

Tags: php

I'm planning about creating a simple script that will allow unexperienced in PHP users create a code files for one video game. I have two files, "code.txt" and "exec.php". The first file looks like this:

```
getglobal_move_call("TurnTarget")
getglobal_move_loadk_call("GenerateCSM", "15")
```

And "exec.php" creates a "temp.php", that imports the user made file. It's filled with  "str_replace" functions, and results supposed to look like this:

```
<?

$temp_line = "TurnTarget(param1)";
file_put_contents($generated_output, $temp_line, FILE_APPEND);
$temp_line = "GenerateCSM(param1, 15)";
file_put_contents($generated_output, $temp_line, FILE_APPEND);

?>
```

But, when I echo my code after these replacements, I'm getting this:

```
<?

 = "TurnTarget(param1)";
 file_put_contents(User/Apple/Sites/Generate/Generated.txt, , FILE_APPEND);
 = "GenerateCSM(param1, 15)";
 file_put_contents(User/Apple/Sites/Generate/Generated.txt, , FILE_APPEND);

?>
```

As you can see, str_replace deleted all variables. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Seems likely that the string you were replacing `$temp_line` with was an empty or null string.  Without seeing any code which demonstrates the problem, what you're asking doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by separating "$" symbol and variable's name.

```
str_replace("templine", "$"."templine", $code);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you use `""` in your code, and PHP replaces `$temp_line` with it's actual value (null, because there is no such var).

To echo PHP code escape your `$` with `\`

[Live demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e4195a633c3cb40d7643b1b0ba73f3505dad1878)

```
$code = <<< PHP
    \$temp_line = "TurnTarget(param1)";
    file_put_contents(\$generated_output, \$temp_line, FILE_APPEND);
    \$temp_line = "GenerateCSM(param1, 15)";
    file_put_contents(\$generated_output, \$temp_line, FILE_APPEND);
PHP;

echo $code;
```